# Ajax success() is not working when calling API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The onClick() event of the button is not directing anywhere.There might be some problem with the success() of ajax.I can't figure out what as I am new to this.

```
var currentAuthor="";
var currentQuote="";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#getMessage").on("click",function(){
  $.ajax({
  header:{ 
      "X-Mashape-Key":"xE5Raw3acMmsh4dpp6HEk5WSbJtTp1X9TL3jsnue3VRzr5vNNa",
   Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
    url:"https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=",
    success: function(response){
      var r=json.parse(response);
      currentQuote=r.quote;
      currentAuthor=r.author;
       $("#author").html(r.author);
    }
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I tried copying your code into a fiddle and i got a 401, the header "X-Mashape-Key" is never added

Comment: So,what am I supposed to do? @Hodrobond

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had 2 problems:

1. header should be `headers`
2. it's `JSON.parse` and not `json.parse`

```js
var currentAuthor = "";
var currentQuote = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#getMessage").on("click", function () {
  $.ajax({
   headers: {
    "X-Mashape-Key": "xE5Raw3acMmsh4dpp6HEk5WSbJtTp1X9TL3jsnue3VRzr5vNNa",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   },
   url: "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=",
   success: function (response) {
    var r = JSON.parse(response);
    currentQuote = r.quote;
    currentAuthor = r.author;
    $("#author").html(r.author);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="getMessage">Get Message</button>
<p id="author"></p>
```

Comment: @aayushi Sure thing :)